# passing Synplify options from Lattice Diamond TCL code

Tags: vhdl, lattice, tcl, generic, synplify

I would like to pass, from the TCL file that is commanding the Diamond tool of Lattice, some options to the Synplify synthesis tool.

E.g.: It is possible to set a value of the VHDL generic at toplevel in the GUI.
https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/fpga/Setting_Generics_Parameters_for_Synthesis/

But when saving this project in TCL (`save_script test.tcl`), this option is not exported to TCL.

Adding the Synplify TCL code in the Lattice TCL file isn't helping.

`set_option -hdl_param -set BUILD_VERSION {x"01"}`

```
pnmainc diamond.tcl
invalid command name "set_option"
    while executing
"set_option -hdl_param -set BUILD_VERSION x"01""
    (file "diamond.tcl" line 3)
```

And the manual not the `help` in Lattice/TCL isn't revealing anything.

I would like to avoid having another TCL file just for Synplify in my repo.

Comment: Are you using LSE or Synplify? I'm avoiding a direct call to `pnmainc`. So I'm calling `synthesis -f <optionfile>` directly.

Comment: @paebbels I'm using Synplify.  But I should check with the owner of the code why :-).  'synthesis.exe' is LSE, I assume.

Answer (score 1):

(I still think it's stupid I can't post that as a comment before 50rep)

Try with the following syntax:

```
hdl_param -set BUILD_VERSION x"01"
```